# Is there any discussion about effects of snap in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I've tried to keep the title fairly vague due to spoiler potential but my question is based on the following concept:

After the snap in *Avengers: Infinity War* "Half of all life" on the planet is gone. It's shown that this includes animals as well as humans. The only reference I can remember from the film is that the governments had managed to "keep going" or "reorganise" following the snap.

My question is, **is there any discussion/context as to how this has actually affected the world at large?** There seems to be little to no issue in terms of quality of life for those who have not been snapped, especially no one starving, etc.

Yet we also see lots of rundown and broken vehicles/buildings etc.

But there is certainly no sign of complete armageddon/end of the world type scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we see plenty of broken down vehicles/buildings in the movie and Captain Marvel indicates that she has to help life adjust on thousands of other worlds. Scientifically [we know](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/science-behind-the-fiction-the-real-world-consequences-of-thanos-snap) that taking half of all life would be pretty disastrous.

That said, the movie shows us up to 23 days after the snap and then 5 years later. It doesn't show us a great deal of what life was like adjusting to the snap. Presumably there was a lot of calamity and misfortune.

There wasn't an apocalypse because it wasn't actually apocalyptic - people survived and started again. We can assume there was localized incidents of starvation, panic, accidents, etc because of the destruction we see on film and from what we know of human nature.

Comment: "it wasn't apocalyptic" - as shown in the movie, sure. But if half (on average) of the people supposed to maintain nuclear plants, power stations, air traffic and such suddenly disappeared... Yeah, we'd have a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any discussion/context as to how this has actually affected the world at large?

Yes there is at least one that I could muster.

In Avengers: Endgame Captain America is trying to look at the things that have gotten better due to the snap. During chat with Black Widow he says he saw a pod of whales in the Hudson and also tells that the environment is much cleaner now.